# Send scheduled message everyday to all users using the slack bot

Tags: python, django, slack, slack-api

I am creating a slack bot project using Django. Here I would like to send a scheduled message to every user of the workspace. Every day, the bot will ask specific questions to all users, but personally.
In that case, how can I post questions every day within a specific schedule?

Which tool or django-package will be appropriate to fulfill my problem?

Comment: you can use slack api to send scheduled message

Comment: Maybe you didn't get it. Slack API only schedules the message to be sent only once, at the specified time. But I want it to send every day.

Comment: then u can use cron